# PHP: Creating dynamic sitemap

Tags: php, web-crawler, sitemap, google-search-console

I was searching for a simple script to generate a dynamic sitemap when i came across what i have below:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' .PHP_EOL; 

    function urlElement($url) {
        echo '<url>'.PHP_EOL; 
        echo '<loc>'.$url.'</loc>'. PHP_EOL; 
        echo '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>'.PHP_EOL; 
        echo '</url>'.PHP_EOL;
    } 

    urlElement('https://www.example.com/sub1'); 
    urlElement('https://www.example.com/sub2'); 
    urlElement('https://www.example.com/sub2'); 
    echo '</urlset>'; 
?>
```

The above code works perfectly to generate a sitemap for the specified urls but i need something that can loop through the specified urls and fetch all the links on them to create a single sitemap while ignoring duplicate links.

Comment: Store your URLs in an array then do a `foreach()` on the array and call `urlElement($value);` on the value within the loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but my knowledge is limited in this area, can you help with exactly what you have just advised?

Comment: See my answer below, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store your URLs in an array then do a foreach() on the array and call urlElement($value); on the value within the loop.

```
<?php 

    function urlElement($url) {
        echo '<url>'.PHP_EOL; 
        echo '<loc>'.$url.'</loc>'. PHP_EOL; 
        echo '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>'.PHP_EOL; 
        echo '</url>'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    $urls = array(
        "http://www.google.com",
        "http://www.google.com/images",
        "http://www.google.com/maps"
    );



    header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' .PHP_EOL; 

    foreach($urls as $value) {
        urlElement($value);
    }

    echo '</urlset>'; 
?>
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to store all of your links in a database if you don't have a static site, and whenever an internal link is added, you add it to the database - then you read the database and pull the info into the `$url` array. There isn't a quick fix for this and will take some programming on your site to get it working.

Alternatively, you can use something like `file_get_contents()` and use a regex to search for any `<a>` tags and store them in an array, but that's very bad on resources if you're doing that for every page and every time a sitemap is loaded.

Comment: content are not stored in database in this case, the website dynamically fetches content using third party API

Comment: Here is what i got from your code: weekly weekly weekly

Comment: View the source as it will be parsed as an xml document

Comment: There is no difference in the source

Comment: It doesn't make any difference from the one i posted, i need it to scrape all the urls on the specified pages and include them in the sitemap. thanks anyway

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what your site is? Like what kind of pages are you accessing/trying to include in your sitemap? Your sitemap should only have pages on your site not external links. Like I said in the above comment, you should really create a script that stores the urls as they are added, rather than scraping each page as they will put strain on your server every time the sitemap is called.

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.armorthemes.com/demo/songcharts/. there are some urls in that pattern and the sitemap for the song list need to be created